# scatter_matrix shows not all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scatter-plot

I've got some problems with my `scatter_matrix` plots.

Basically I've got a dataframe df consisting of 19 columns, i.e.

```
df.columns = ['A','B',...'S']
```

The column 'A' contains only int values between 1 and 2.
The scatter_matrix applied to df

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df,diagonal = 'kde', ax = ax_values1_2)
```

returns the desired **19x19 matrix plot**.

If I split the dataframe in two seperate dataframes df_1 and df_2 which consits of the same data except that df_1 consits of all values where `df.A = 1` and analog df_2 got the values where `df.A=2`.

If I now apply scatter_matrix to These new dataframes:

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df_1,diagonal = 'kde', ax = ax_values1_2)
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df_2,diagonal = 'kde', ax = ax_values1_2)
```

I get 2 metrices of size **9x9**.

So I guess 'scatter_matrix' filters the rows out of the plot, where there seems to be no relevant Information. Am I right at this point?

So my question is: how to force `scatter_matrix` to plot the full `19` columns even there might be no sense.

Maybe there is some theretical or easy answer for this problem. If not I could deliver in addition the Code that causes the problem.

Comment: Your question would definitely benefit from a [MCVE].

Comment: Specifically for pandas, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for all the advises to improve the quality of asking for help.

Meanwhile I found a solution for my problem. In case someone else would be faced with the same Problem, the solution for me was to change the `diagonal` Parameter in `scatter_matrix` to `hist`.

It seems that scatter_matrix won't throw aways colums with only one single value per column if `hist` is chosen.